# Intelligent Product Recommendation

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, artificial-intelligence

I would like to ask something about the implementation of Intelligent Product Recommendation

As I need to build an online shopping system using JSP and Mysql, I want to implement a function,

which can automatically recommend some related products when the user checks for one product details.

However, I did not have any learning experience for Artificial Intelligence.

There are too many resources on the Internet but I don't know which are good for learning.

Therefore, would anyone suggest some useful websites for studying such type of programming skill(that is, AI).

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement "recommender system".

Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system

Very good resource, from there you can go to the explanations of recommender algorithms and their implementations.

In your case, I believe that best algorithm will be item-to-item collaborative filtering (it is used by Amazon, for example).

Answer (score 1):

This book will definitely help you:
["Algorithms of the Intelligent Web"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988665)
It has some cool explanations of how it works and how you can implement that.

Answer (score 0):

If you havrn't AI skills, you should use ready to use software, I would recommend open source Taste(http://taste.sourceforge.net/) Don't be confused with mahhot project, it is not required hadoop cluster if you data is not very big (gigabites)